# Finding if volume has crossed moving average in the past few candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Currently I trade manually and use volume as an extra confluence.  If any of the past few volume bars have gone over the moving average and at the same time (for a long) printed a red candle then that's a positive.

I'm trying to recreate this in pinescript, but it's not doing what i'd hope

This is what I have so far:

```
volume_cross(lookbackLength, maLength) =>
    for offset = 0 to lookbackLength - 1
        volumeMa=ta.sma(volume[offset],maLength)
        if ta.crossover(volumeMa,volume[offset]) and close[offset]<open[offset]
            true

plotchar(volume_cross(5,20), title="volume_cross")
```

I'm new to pinescript and i've not written a function or even a loop in this before!

Not only is it not doing what I hope but i'm getting warnings that the ta functions should be called on each calculation, so I assume there's a better way to do this

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ta.barssince()` to figure out when was the last time since volume has crossed moving average.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

vol_ema = ta.ema(volume, 20)
vol_ema_cross = ta.crossover(volume, vol_ema)
bars_since_cross = ta.barssince(vol_ema_cross)
plot(bars_since_cross)
```

[image]